# Dropdown menu not showing the listed elements when hovered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason this dropdown menu is not showing the listed elements when hovered. Using bootstrap.

Am I missing something here? Maybe it's something simple but I just cannot see it.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Services -->
<li class="nav-item dropdown">

  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rewiring</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Light Fixes</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Showers</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rewiring</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Light Fixes</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Showers</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you also add the CSS that registers this hover action?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to a [mcve] and tag the bootstrap version

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](//stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, dropdown runs by default on mouse click, if you want to show dropdown on mouse hover then you have to use css or js

I have used css

```
.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{ display: block; }
```

```css
.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{ display: block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Services
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</h6></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rewiring</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Light Fixes</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Showers</a></li>
      <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rewiring</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Light Fixes</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Showers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More things to talk about here:

1. Opening dropdown in BS is done by `Popper.js` (which is not part of `bootstrap.min.js`). So in order to make dropdown working, you need to load Bootstrap JS via bundle, where Popper.js is included
   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
2. Since you are using BS5, you need to change `data-toggle="dropdown"` to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`. That is new markup from version 5 onwards.
3. As mentioned in another answer, opening dropdown on click (and not hover) is core part of BS philosophy (unfortunately). So in case you want to open submenu on hover, additional CSS has to be added.
4. Also be careful with the markup. It would be more clean to use the structure recommended by BS for the navigation (using `<ul>`, `<li>`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

change `<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>`

to

`<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown button </button>`

Change it to a button then it shoud work!!